# Create a loop to compile multiple records into a new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

At the moment I am fetching metadata attached to individual record numbers. The process I am using works, but its somewhat cumbersome, especially for larger batches of records:

```js
var a = 'metadatafrom_123456_record-as_record:record_name,record_date';
var b = 'metadatafrom_23456_record-as_record:record_name,record_date';
var c = 'metadatafrom_789456_record-as_record:record_name,record_date';
var allData = [...a, ...b, ...c];
console.log(allData);
```

I am trying to improve this process by creating a loop or sorts to insert each record number to get the same result as above in allData.

```js
var numbers = [123456, 23456, 789456];
var allData = [];

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  console.log(numbers[i]);
  allData = metadatafrom_numbers[i]_record-as_record:record_name,record_date;
} 

console.log(allData);
```

However, I am not getting allData in console or any error.

Comment: I've placed your code into 2 snippets so you can see the second one do produce an error. Guess the first one also does not output as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allData.push() is good

```js
var numbers = [123456, 23456, 789456];
var allData = [];

for (let num of numbers) {
  allData.push(`metadatafrom_${num}_record-as_record:record_name,record_date`);
}

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
const numbers = [123456, 23456, 789456];
let allData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
    allData.push(`metadatafrom_${numbers[i]}_record-as_record:record_name,record_date`);
} 

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do get an error because you forgot to quote as string:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

---

You can use [inline strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (to prevent overriding the array) like so:

```js
var numbers = [123456, 23456, 789456];
var allData = [];

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  allData.push(`metadatafrom_${numbers[i]}_record-as_record:record_name,record_date`);
} 

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map(), the problem can be solved using it.

```js
var numbers = [123456, 23456, 789456];
const allData = numbers.map(num => `metadatafrom_${num}_record-as_record:record_name,record_date`);

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score -1):

you sould use allData.push instead of allData = .... :

```
allData.push( metadatafrom_numbers[i]_record-as_record:record_name,record_date);
```